# What is the difference between myArray.GetValue(2) and myArray[2] in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there any difference between using myArray.GetValue(2) and myArray[2]?

For example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            Console.WriteLine(numbers.GetValue(3));
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[3]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not in the code you wrote. It's useful for non 0-based arrays and in languages without support for indexer (or for arrays...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetValue` will return type object while using the index will return the type specific with the array.

You can see in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xfE7lS) (code below) that the variable `val1` can have a string stored in it, but `val2` can only be used as an integer.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
    var val1 = numbers.GetValue(3);
    var type = val1.GetType();
    var val2 = numbers[3];

    Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
    val1 = "hello";
    type = val1.GetType();
    Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
}
```

This will result in [boxing and unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), which won't have an effect on a small code snippet, but if used in large scale it could potentially affect performance.

Comment: Thank you, nicely explained :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, there isn't a difference.  The primary difference, inside an array when you call `Array.GetValue(1)` you're receiving the value of that index.  You can't specifically set the value of the array though.

If you were to do `Array[1] = "...";` you've modified the array.  But you can also still attain the value, though it may not be as expressive as above.  So you can get or set a value with this approach.

> The number of elements in indices must equal the number of dimensions
>   in the Array. All elements in the indices array must collectively
>   specify the position of the desired element in the multidimensional
>   Array. The GetLowerBound and GetUpperBound methods can determine
>   whether any of the indexes is out of bounds. This method is an O(1)
>   operation.

Both are susceptible do the above though.

Answer (score 1):

`numbers.GetValue(3)` returns an object and therefor the overload [Console.WriteLine(object value)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an `object` parameter is called.

`numbers[3]` is of type `int` and then [Console.WriteLine(int value)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70x4wcx1(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an `int` as parameter is called.

So you end up calling different methods.

Answer (score 0):

In use-ability there isn't a difference except for setting values. The difference however seems to be in how it gets the value.

Array's `.GetValue` gives me [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,251c99c8419d33d4,references), it returns an object.

Either approach takes under 1ms so there isn't a substantial speed difference either.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Array class(with uppercase) there are not indexers. So the way you can get and set elements on it is using GetValue() or SetValue()
See this link : [Using an array's SetValue method vs. the [] indexers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626892/using-an-arrays-setvalue-method-vs-the-indexers)