# Assign a GUID in C#

Tags: c#, guid

I have a string representation of the Guid,I'm doing some testing and I'm hard-coding some GUIDs into the code. The below way can assign Guid of single value.

```
Guid g = new Guid("11223344-5566-7788-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00");
```

Now, My question is how i can assign values to an array list of `Guid[]`?

Comment: Have you tried a ... loop? Or are you asking how to initialize an array? Latter would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-array-initialization-syntaxes

Comment: [Collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)?

Comment: Do you know how to assign a value to an array element for, say, an array of integers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code snippet to assign values to an array list of Guid[]

```
        Guid[] arr = new Guid[4];
        arr.SetValue(new Guid("11223344-5566-7788-99AA-BBCCDDEEFF00"), 0);
        arr.SetValue(new Guid("26a285e5-5435-4daa-8d36-3186bd441cff"), 1);
        arr.SetValue(new Guid("6d850084-d55a-45a9-9e83-5adf22cfbf04"), 2);
        arr.SetValue(new Guid("ec43e526-51c0-41bc-b04a-2f2e72c894cc"), 3);
```

You can use the below code snippet to fill out your Guid array with randomly generated Guids.

```
        Guid[] arr = new Guid[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            arr.SetValue(Guid.NewGuid(), i);
        }
```

Comment: Why no simply `arr[0] = new Guid("...")`? `arr.SetValue` is not idiomatic.

Comment: @KlausGütter Please refer to this answer, it may answer your query better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626921/6607452

Comment: Yes, but here you have a `Guid[]` which definitely supports `[]`